# Ensure generic vararg parameters have the same type

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I would like to implement method that makes comparison of objects of the same type.

Is it feasible to implement `isOnceOf()` to be compile time type strict and give me compilation error at line 3?
Currently I'm getting only warning.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isOneOf(3, 1, 2, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(isOneOf("A", "B", "C", "D")); // false
    System.out.println(isOneOf(1, "B", "C", "D")); // false, warn
}

public static <T> boolean isOneOf(T obj, T mate, T... mates) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj.equals(mate)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (T m : mates) {
        if (obj.equals(m)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Type-inference working against you =/.

Comment: Actually, yes, you can: `System.out.println(MyClass.<Integer>isOneOf(1, "B", "C", "D"));` will fail. But you can't force the caller to use this form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9299194/1743880 also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17390441/1743880. Also related http://stackoverflow.com/q/26538980/1743880

Comment: For me, the only solution is the one shown here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9299194/1743880. Add a `Class<T>` parameter.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The reason you can't do it is because there is no type-safety reason to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to implement type-safe variant of `Arrays.asList(value1, value2).contains(value3)`. Common usage would be to use in if statements when some value is asserted against multiply constant values. Type-safeness is to eliminate any possibility of typo as list of values could be large and constants could be of different types.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych: It is already type-safe. Generics is not for you to impose arbitrary constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Tunaki. Next works as expected.

```
public static <O, T extends O> boolean isMember(O obj, T mate, T... mates) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj.equals(mate)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (T m : mates) {
        if (obj.equals(m)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `MyClass.<Object, Object>isMember(1, "B", "C", "D")` still compiles for example.

Comment: the point is to help user to eliminate typos, if user wants to code some bugs it is up to him )

Comment: It's not a "bug" -- it is perfectly type-safe.